# Should authorization be atomic with operation?

Tags: database, security, rest, database-design

**Question: Should authorization be atomic with operation?**

Let me explain.

User A is making an API call to view an entity. This call requires two steps.

1. Verify user A is authorized to view/edit the entity.
2. Return the entity to user A.

At the same time, User B is making a call to modify the entity. The new entity User B is posting not only adds new info to the entity, but also removes User A from the authorized users list. This call requires two steps.

1. Verify user B is authorized to view/edit the entity.
2. Update the entity with the new entity User B has provided.

If authorization is not atomic the back end may process the requests like this.

1. Verify user A is authorized to view/edit the entity. (From User A's API call)
2. Verify user B is authorized to view/edit the entity. (From User B's API call)
3. Update the entity with the new entity User B has provided. (From User B's API call)
4. Return the entity to user A. (From User A's API call)

This is problematic because User A would have received info he was not authorized to see.

Is this a significant issue, or am I grasping at straws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will in theory always have this race condition unless the request-response cycles are atomic.

I think your concern is as follows:

1. B wants to post something that A should not see.
2. B revokes A's rights with one HTTP request.
3. B waits for the HTTP response that confirms the operation
4. B waits another 10 minutes "just to be sure."
5. B posts the updated data on a new request.

Even here you still have a race if A's request for the data was on another thread which was horrifically slow.

You have two solutions:

If you use an evented server you might be able to do a revocation and update in a single work unit.

Another approach is for B's edit to have different access rights so A can not see the new stuff but continue to see the old stuff.

Comment: It is an evented sever via the use of transactions which I am already using. I only hesitated to do this as it makes the code a bit cleaner and the transactions shorter to do it outside the transaction. My question really is if I should worry about it at all, but it sounds like you are saying that if I have the opportunity to do that I should, a.k.a do the authorization check inside the transaction that is doing the operation.

Comment: I think it is very much an edge case.  Yes, the code is cleaner if one request revokes A's rights and then a subsequent request adds the data that A should not see.  How dangerous is it for A to see the new data?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a significant issue.

Even if the events are not happening simultaneously then also A can view the info if B has not updated it already. A user can always see information until the view rights are revoked.